# RxJava map produces a different return type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm using RxJava with retrofit in order to do my network calls. In my code I have a retrofit call that returns a `Single<Result<List<SpoonacularResult>>>`. I have another function that calls the retrofit function and uses map to transform it into a Kotlin.Result. Another function takes the Kotlin.Result and changes it into another Kotlin.Result so that my UI can take the results and do whatever. The Problem I' running into is that after getRecipesViewModel calls getRecipes, the type of processedResult is `Single<Result<Result<List<SpoonacularResult>>>`. This only happens when my getRecipesRetrofit returns an error, it works completely fine when it returns a success. I'm not sure where the extra Result wrapping the inner Result comes from. Below is my code and some pictures to help illustrate what I'm talking about since the bug is a bit weird to explain.

[returnResult type from getRecipes](https://gyazo.com/d508cda013aefb313c5a57b8b70b6956)

[processedResult from getRecipesViewModel](https://gyazo.com/83fa63d2cfa6b07fc4e427b57e2ca568)

```html
@GET("recipes/findByIngredients?number=50&ranking=2")
    fun getRecipesRetrofit(@Query("ingredients", encoded = true) ingredients: String, @Query("apiKey") apiKey: String)
            : Single<RxResult<List<SpoonacularResult>>>
```

```html
fun getRecipes(ingredients: String): Single<KtResult<List<SpoonacularResult>>> {
        return spoonService.getRecipesRetrofit(ingredients, "ApiKey").map { result ->
            val processedResult = responseProcessor.process(result)
            val returnResult = if (processedResult.isFailure()) {
                KtResult.failure(processedResult.error!!)
            } else {
                KtResult.success(processedResult.body!!)
            }
            returnResult
        }
    }
```

```html
fun getRecipesViewModel(set: MutableSet<String>): Single<Result<Int>> {
        val ingredients = setUpSet(set)
        return service.getRecipes(ingredients).map { processedResult ->
            val networkResult = if (processedResult.isFailure) {
                val error = processedResult.exceptionOrNull()!!
                Result.failure(error)
            } else {
                val resultBody = processedResult.getOrNull()!!
                if (resultBody.isNotEmpty()) {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        recipeDao.clearRecipes()
                        resultBody.forEach {
                            recipeDao.insertRecipe(it)
                        }
                    }
                    Result.success(1)
                } else {
                    Result.success(2)
                }
            }
            networkResult
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type does `responseProcessor.process(result)` return? Looks like you are overnesting items.

Comment: `class ProcessedResult<T>(
        val error: Throwable?,
        val message: String?,
        val body: T?
    )` The responseProcessor takes retrofit's result, extracts the information, and converts it to a processedResult.

Comment: Could you post the entire project on github or similar?